# Math.random range using the size of an arraylist

Tags: java, random, arraylist

```
public void pickWinner() {
      int last = list.size() - 1;
      int number = (int)Math.random()*last;
      System.out.println("And the winner is...");
      Student winner = list.get(number);
      System.out.println(winner);
}
```

I am having problems generating a winner other than the first item in the ArrayList. I am thinking it is a problem with Math.random() because the size of my ArrayList seems to be correct, but it seems to only be generating 0's to get the first term in my ArrayList. What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
int number = (int)(Math.random()*last);
```

The problem is you're casting the math.random value to an int before multiplying it. The cast has a higher operator precedence (for a complete list, see http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/)

Additionally, your code will never pick the last Student in the list, you shouldn't -1 the 'last' int.

You could also consider using the Random class, i.e. `new java.util.Random().nextInt(list.size());` so you don't have to worry about casts and how ints get rounded. You can even re-use the Random instance if you need to do it more than once.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works perfectly. I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out what stupid mistake I had made.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` generates a number between `0.0` and `1.0`. You are doing an integer conversion BEFORE you mulitply last, so the random number gets floored down to 0 and then the overall result will be always zero.

```
  int number = (int)(Math.random()*last);
```

should work correctly